# Python3 name error-I am trying to make a twitter-bot using python 3, Unfortunately my code throws name errors and I cant figure out why

Tags: python, json, ubuntu, bots, tweepy

I am trying to build a python twitter-bot and I am surprised that python gives me name errors, please guide me out I don't know whether the problem is with json or urllib.request or python.
I am trying to run the code directly in ubuntu 14.04 terminal with python 3.4.
Here is my code.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import json, io, tweepy, time, urllib.request
from secrets import *
from random import randint
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(C_KEY, C_SECRET)  
auth.set_access_token(A_TOKEN, A_TOKEN_SECRET)  
api = tweepy.API(auth)
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dariusk/corpora/master/data/humans/occupations.json') as list1file:
    list1read = list1file.read().decode('utf8')
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dariusk/corpora/master/data/animals/dogs.json') as list2file:
    list2read = list2file.read().decode('utf8')
    list1 = json.loads(list1read)['occupations'] 
    list2 = json.loads(list2read)['dogs']
    jokelist = []
    counter = 0
    while counter < 2:
        list1num = randint(0, len(list1)-1)
        list2num = randint(0, len(list2)-1)
        first = list1[list1num].lower()
        second = list2[list2num].lower()
    if second[0] in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
        third = 'an'
    else:
        third = 'a'
        joke = 'A {} is better than {} {}' .format(first, third, second)
        print (joke)
        jokelist.append(joke)
        counter = counter + 1

for line in jokelist:
    api.update_status(line)
    time.sleep(15)

print ('[All done!]')
```

On execution, I get the following errors.

> > > joke = 'A {} is better than {} {}' .format(first, third, second)
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       NameError: name 'first' is not defined
> > >
> > > print (joke)
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       NameError: name 'joke' is not defined
> > >
> > > jokelist.append(joke)
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       NameError: name 'joke' is not defined

I am new to programming and I will accept any help accorded.

Comment: third is only defined if the else clause is invoked.

Comment: I don't think this is the actual code that generates these errors.  As your listing stands the execution will never escape from the `while counter < 2` loop.

Comment: thank you so how should I write that part of the code?

Comment: thanks @PaulCornelius, let me remove the while and see..

Comment: @PaulCornelius still it isn't working.. any suggestions?

Comment: @steve254 I think it's an indentation problem with the code you posted.  Please check that.

Comment: thank you @PaulCornelius i removed the `while counter < 2` loop and then went ahead and indented the code.. it now works like a charm, thanks.